# Which type of path to store in MySQL database?

Tags: php, sql, mysql

When I come to build a simple site using PHP and MySQL, what is the best method for storing paths of files and images?

- Inserting paths to Mysql as (system path `C:/----`)
- Inserting paths to Mysql as (HTTP path `http://----`)

Comment: That entirely depends on what you need to use the data for.

The two methods are not interchangeable, it's like comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: none of these. but path from the site root. or what Nicholas said

Answer (score 5):

Always save file paths relative to your web sites directory. Consider your website's address is "foo.com" and you want to store images in "foo.com/images". It better to store images address without "http" and without "foo.com".

Therefore just save the filename and its subfolder if exists.

Comment: what about if you can generate address? just save has avatar?

Answer (score 3):

Neither, the best is to store just the filename and leave your application to determine where to locate this file. You can determine it accordingly to your database table. For example, let's say we have an user table which have an avatar field. You can store just the filename (foo.jpg), and then determine the path in your application (c:\xampp\htdocs\project1\img\users\foo.jpg). Or even better, you can leave this field and store nothing about the image, then you can check if an image exists with the id of the user, like 1.jpg, 2.jpg etc.

But, if you really want to store absolute paths, start storing from your project folder. For example, lets say you have `c:\xampp\htdocs\my_project\module1` Then, start from `/module1`

If you need to store a external URL you can save the entire like `http://www.foo.com/test`

Answer (score 1):

I propose you save the relative path, not the absolute one. I.e, if you have this structure:

```
c:/install_folder/
c:/install_folder/script.php
c:/install_folder/files/file.jpg
```

Store "file.jpg" as "files/file.jpg". Thenn save "c:/install_folder/" in a configuration value somewhere in your application. That way you can easily move the application around and just update the configuration file.

Comment: the path should be absolute one. strictly absolute. But from the site root

Comment: Col. Shrapnel, that is what I said too. Have you even read my answer? It's relative to the site root (not absolute, since absolute means the ful system path or the full URL).

Comment: no, you do not understand the terms. website has it's own absolute paths as well. the / folder is a perfect root for the website, and you can build any absolute path out of it. "absolute" means "equally accessible being called from anywhere". So, by calling /images/pic.jpg from any folder of your site, you will get this image. thus, it's perfectly absolute path

Comment: I think we mean the same thing :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just save the image name and let your application handle directory building.

Including the path whether, absolute, virtual or the web address will add an overhead of the file path data to each entry in the image field column.

If you must store this information in your database why not store it as a foreign key to a paths table.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you use your data. When you want as example edit your file the best solution is to use the system path. And when you want, as example link to another page you can use the HTTP path